# Can't use di (Dependency Injection) in product list class rewrite for json Helper

Tags: magento2

I have tried to used json helper class in my rewrited list file.

But it gives error like this

```
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Kite\Boxes\Block\Rewrite\Product\ListProduct::__construct() must be an instance of Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data, instance of Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context given, called in /var/www/vhosts/goweb-dev01.site/httpdocs/var/generation/Kite/Boxes/Block/Rewrite/Product/ListProduct/Interceptor.php on line 14 and defined in /var/www/vhosts/goweb-dev01.site/httpdocs/app/code/Kite/Boxes/Block/Rewrite/Product/ListProduct.php:7 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/vhosts/goweb-dev01.site/httpdocs/var/generation/Kite/Boxes/Block/Rewrite/Product/ListProduct/Interceptor.php(14): Kite\Boxes\Block\Rewrite\Product\ListProduct->__construct(Object(Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context), Object(Magento\Framework\Data\Helper\PostHelper), Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver), Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryRepository), Object(Magento\Framework\Url\Helper\Data), Array) #1 /var/www/vhosts/goweb-dev01.site/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php in /var/www/vhosts/goweb-dev01.site/httpdocs/app/code/Kite/Boxes/Block/Rewrite/Product/ListProduct.php on line 7
```

My code in file

```
    <?php
namespace Kite\Boxes\Block\Rewrite\Product;
class ListProduct extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct
{
    protected $jsonHelper;

    public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data $jsonHelper)
    {
        $this->jsonHelper = $jsonHelper;
    }

    public function getProductCollectinJsonData()
    {
        $_productCollection = $this->getLoadedProductCollection()->addTierPriceData();
        $i                  = 0;
        $ProductData        = array();
        foreach ($_productCollection as $product) {
            if ($product->getTypeId() == 'simple') {
                $ProductData[$i]['Product Name'] = $product->getName();
                if ($product->getTierPrice()) {
                    $tierPriceList = $product->getTierPrice();
                    if (count($tierPriceList) > 0) {
                        $ProductData[$i]['1-' . (intval($tierPriceList[0]['price_qty'])) . ' Packs'] = $tierPriceList[0]['price'];
                    }
                    $count = 0;
                    foreach ($tierPriceList as $key => $trList) {
                        if ($count == (count($tierPriceList) - 1)) {
                            $ProductData[$i][intval($trList['price_qty']) . '+ Packs'] = number_format($trList['price'], 2);
                        } else {
                            $ProductData[$i][intval($trList['price_qty'] + 1) . '-' . (intval($tierPriceList[$key + 1]['price_qty'])) . ' Packs'] = number_format($trList['price'], 2);
                        }

                        $count++;
                    }
                }
                $i++;
            }
        }
        return $this->jsonHelper->jsonDecode($jsonData);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to execute `php bin/magento setup:di:compile` and check

Comment: It ask for parent argument.is there need to pass parent argument on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is full working code.

```
    <?php
namespace Kite\Boxes\Block\Rewrite\Product;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface; /* line added */
use Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data as jsondata; /* line added */
class ListProduct extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct
{
    /*protected $jsonHelper;*/

    /*public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data $jsonHelper)
    {
        $this->jsonHelper = $jsonHelper;
    }*/

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Helper\PostHelper $postDataHelper,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver $layerResolver,
        CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository,
        \Magento\Framework\Url\Helper\Data $urlHelper,
        array $data = [],
        jsondata $jsonHelper
    ) {
        $this->jsonHelper = $jsonHelper;
        $this->_catalogLayer = $layerResolver->get();
        $this->_postDataHelper = $postDataHelper;
        $this->categoryRepository = $categoryRepository;
        $this->urlHelper = $urlHelper;
        parent::__construct(
            $context,
            $postDataHelper,
            $layerResolver,
            $categoryRepository,
            $urlHelper,
            $data

        );
    }

    public function getProductCollectinJsonData()
    {
        $_productCollection = $this->getLoadedProductCollection()->addTierPriceData();
        $i                  = 0;
        $ProductData        = array();
        foreach ($_productCollection as $product) {
            if ($product->getTypeId() == 'simple') {
                $ProductData[$i]['Product Name'] = $product->getName();
                if ($product->getTierPrice()) {
                    $tierPriceList = $product->getTierPrice();
                    if (count($tierPriceList) > 0) {
                        $ProductData[$i]['1-' . (intval($tierPriceList[0]['price_qty'])) . ' Packs'] = $tierPriceList[0]['price'];
                    }
                    $count = 0;
                    foreach ($tierPriceList as $key => $trList) {
                        if ($count == (count($tierPriceList) - 1)) {
                            $ProductData[$i][intval($trList['price_qty']) . '+ Packs'] = number_format($trList['price'], 2);
                        } else {
                            $ProductData[$i][intval($trList['price_qty'] + 1) . '-' . (intval($tierPriceList[$key + 1]['price_qty'])) . ' Packs'] = number_format($trList['price'], 2);
                        }

                        $count++;
                    }
                }
                $i++;
            }
        }
        return $this->jsonHelper->jsonEncode($ProductData);
    }
}
```

also remove var/generation folder to make it working

```
rm -rf var/generation
```

Comment: please accept this as your answer, so this question is marked as solved :)

Comment: I will but for now i can't it ask after two days :(

Answer (score 2):

You have to copy the constructor of `\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct` into your class and add your additional arguments at the end of it.

You also have to call `parent::construct([...])`, where `[...]` means the parent's arguments in the correct order, to set things up.

Comment: yes i did it but not work

Answer (score 1):

Change your constructor as below:

You need to call parent construct and pass dependancy over there to resolve this issue.

[image]

Comment: Have added but its giving `__construct() must be an instance of Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data, none given, `

Comment: which magento version are you using and have you cleared var/generation folder after updating code?